# IOS/Xcode/Coredata: How to force reload from NSFetchedResults Controller When Modal Controller Dismisssed

Tags: ios, core-data, modalviewcontroller

I have a detail view controller (part of master detail) and an edit screen that appears modally.  After you save edit changes, the modal edit screen is dismissed, leaving the detail screen.

What is the best way to get the detail screen to refresh to show the changes made to the managed object context.

Normally the FRC is lazy loaded so the first time it appears it has new data but in this case, I think the screen is already there behind the modal edit screen so when the edit screen is dismissed, it continues to show old data.

Can I use something in lifecycle or how would I know the Detail VC know its back at top of stack?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: viewWillAppear, or viewDidAppear on the detailVC? Do you dismiss the modal VC in code? Maybe trigger a delegate method in the modal view that gets fired in the detailVC

Comment: You could use the fetchedResultsController delegate methods to update the tableView.  That way you don't need to specifically refresh the table view when the modal screen is dismissed.

Comment: The willchangecontent and did change object methods--at least in the documentation code--update table view.  However my detail VC does not use a table view--it just has a bunch of labels and a photo.  Would I have to update every single element?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were using a tableView.  My mistake.  As per JamesSugrue, I would just update the labels/photo in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Not sure viewWIllAppaer is getting called.

Comment: Can you give more detail of your setup, including the code for the detail view controller and the modal edit screen.  Thanks.

Comment: When I put a NSLog statement in viewWIllAppear of detail view it does not fire when modal (edit) is dismissed.  Currently modal dismisses itself when you save it as done button is wired to a save method that includes: if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Dismiss View Controller
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            ;

Comment: If there is a way to trigger a refresh in the presenting (detail) controller, that line could go before the dismissal above.  Or I guess I could do the save and dismissal method from the presenting (detail) controller, however, that would require using a delegate pattern I think which I'm not sure how to do if no table involved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75741/discussion-between-pbasdf-and-user1904273).