# ios/xcode/coredata: How to refresh detail view in Master Detail setup

Tags: ios, core-data, reload, presentviewcontroller

I want to refresh the detail page in a MasterDetail Project.  (The detail should be refreshed after an edit is made in a modal controller.)  I know where to put the block of code in the detail page to force the refresh. I just don't know what code to use to do this.

This detail page does not have a table view.  It just uses text labels and image label.

The NSFetchedResultsController that would refresh the data upon a new fetch is not in this view controller but in the table view from which this detail is derived.

Is there no way to refresh the data in a detail page similar to [[self tableView] reloadData]; in a table page?

Here is code presenting modal view controller where I need to put code block.

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: editVC];
    // Do whatever setup you want to here for your title bar, etc
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:^{
       //CODE TO EXECUTE TO REFRESH CONTROLLER GOES HERE
    }];
```

What code can I put that will refresh controller?

I think it would be the same code that would refresh a detail view controller anywhere in the file.

Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT:  I may be wrong that the above code will execute upon dismissal of modal.  It may just execute upon completion of animation.

However, I am still looking for code to refresh a view controller that is not a tableview from a fetchedresultscontroller akin to [[self tableView] reloadData]; if there was tableview here.

Edit2:

I am trying to refresh in two different places the following save method for the edits (which does successfully save the data and dismiss the modal edit controller.  It just doesn't update the detail screen after the modal edit screen disappears).  (My understanding is self is really short in this case for self.presentingViewController which does the actual dismissing.)

```
if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Dismiss View Controller
            NSLog(@"Presenting controller%@",[self.presentingViewController class]);
            ItemDetailVC *detailVC = [[ItemDetailVC alloc] init];//VC instantiated to be able to call method but this is probably an error as per Mundi's comment below
            [detailVC reloadViewData];           
            NSLog(@"About to dismiss modal editVC");
            [super dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                NSLog(@"in middle of dimissing");
                ItemDetailVC *detailVC = [[ItemDetailVC alloc] init];
                [detailVC reloadViewData];
            }
```

Here is method reloadViewData in detail VC.

in detail.m

```
 -(void)reloadViewData {
  //short version of UI          
        self.itemLabel.text = self.item.name;
        self.itemSub.text = self.item.sub;
        NSLog(@"In detail controller and about to call setneedsdisplay");
        [self.itemLabel setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.itemSub setNeedsDisplay];
    }
```

This approach does get reloadViewData in the detail controller to fire (based on log output) but does not update view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IOS/Xcode/Coredata: How to force reload from NSFetchedResults Controller When Modal Controller Dismisssed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736836/ios-xcode-coredata-how-to-force-reload-from-nsfetchedresults-controller-when-mo)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  The other question doesn't have an answer.  Also this code goes in another place.  It's obvious you marked this as a duplicate because your suggestion on the other question of using viewWillAppear didn't pan out.

Comment: Your code update reveals another problem. You have to dismiss the edit controller to reveal the detail controller "beneath" it, not create a new detail controller!

Comment: Yes that makes sense.  The reason I alloc inited a new detail controller was to have access to the method loadDetail but you are right, I am creating a new instance and reloading it in that instance, not in the one already there.  Problem is I don't know how to call method in previous detail controller as [detailVC loadView] throws error message without creating fresh instance of detailVC.

Answer (score 1):

Right, the completion block will run after the presentation of the controller, not after it is dismissed.

There are several ways to do this:

- You could have the detail view controller be the **delegate** of the edit view controller. Upon dismissal, the edit VC will inform the detail VC of the changes which can then update its UI;
- Another possibility is to simply save the edited managed object and have the detail VC listen to the a **notification**, the  `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`;
- An even simpler method would be to have make the detail VC the responder of the dismiss button of the edit VC and handle the UI update there.

There is no equivalent to `reloadData` of a table view. Just like in a table view you have to write your own code to put the correct data into the labels of the table cells, you have to also write your own code to populate the custom labels and views of your detail view. Just make a method `reloadViewData` and use it to both initialize and update your view.

Comment: I created a method that sets labels to the values as per the edit above.  However, that code in the detail view is in the viewdidload method.  We are back to the question of how you reload the page as I tried to call viewdidload from the edit page but while that method did get called (from log output), it did not update the page.

Comment: You should not call viewDidLoad yourself. Call the routine that updates the UI via one of the three methods I described in my answer. The typical setup is with a  **delegate**.

Comment: I am using the delegate protocol NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate to update the tableVIew.  And the detail view also registers for this delegate protocol.  However the recommended delegate methods from Apple's doc all reference tableviews.  I've tried to get them to work with detail without success.  The code suggested by apple is too long to post here but it can be seen at this link. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html